# Why does FragmentStatePagerAdapter catch exceptions silently?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I found that FragmentStatePagerAdapter(or something else, maybe ViewPager, I don't know) catches exceptions silently and causes ANR.

For Example:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<String> data;

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> data) {
        super(fm);
        int a = 1 / 0; // ANR instead of crash
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        int a = 1 / 0; // ANR instead of crash
        return MyFragment.newInstance(data.get(pos));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int a = 1 / 0; // ANR instead of crash
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        int a = 1 / 0; // ANR instead of crash
        return data.get(position);
    }
}
```

All I can found in the logcat is:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(14277): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(14277): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a2d9a8)
```

What should I do to enable the logcat(for debug)?
My current workaround is adding try-catch for every method in FragmentStatePagerAdapter.